# XSockets on Linux for WebRTC Voice Conferencing Setup?

Tags: webrtc, xsockets.net

I am very new to WebRTC and XSockets. 
I have been struggling to work out how to start coding a WebRTC app running through XSockets. Ideally my production server would be running Ubuntu or similar but all I see is talk about Visual Studio, MVC etc. But I have also read it works perfectly with Mono on any platform.

Would someone be able to explain to me (in the simplest terms possible) the steps I need to take to make a XSockets/WebRTC page run?

Thanks!

Comment: So are you using Xamarin or what development environment (IDE) are you usig? It will be easy to setup WebRTC for Linux. All you need is a server running and then you need the webplatform of choice to run the WebRTC javascript API's in.

Comment: @Uffe I'm actually just using Textastic on OS X. When you say webplatform, what exactly do you mean? Sorry, I'm new to this. I'm great with typical PHP applications etc but this is out of my current scope.